# Combine client-side and server-side validation in Bootstrap 4 form

Tags: validation, bootstrap-4, cherrypy

I have a Bootstrap 4 form with an input field, called `runname`. I want to perform the following validation on the input field:

- `runname` cannot be empty
- `runname` cannot contain spaces
- `runname`cannot already be used previously

I already have the code for a form which gives an error, using [custom Bootstrap styles](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#custom-styles) if the input field is empty:

```js
// JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 order-md1">
      <form class="needs-validation" novalidate method="post" action="#">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="inputRunname" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Run name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputRunname" name="runname" placeholder="Run name" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please enter a run name
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

And I have some Javascript to check if an input contains spaces:

```js
function cannotContainWhiteSpace(input, errorId, name) {
  var value = input.value;
  var errMsgHolder = document.getElementById(errorId);
  if (!(/^\S*$/.test(value))) {
    errMsgHolder.innerHTML =
      'The ' + name + ' cannot contain whitespace';
    input.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

And I also have some Python code on my Cherrypy backend which does a lookup in the database to see if the `runname` already exists:

```
try:
    myConnection = mysql.connector.connect(host=self.database['host'], user=self.database['user'], passwd=self.database['passwd'], db=self.database['db'])
    cursor = myConnection.cursor(buffered=True)

    # unless overriden by the force flag, check whether the runname has already been used before
    if not force:
        reusedrunquery = "SELECT run FROM logs WHERE run = %s AND errormessage IS NULL"
        cursor.execute(reusedrunquery, (runname,))
        if cursor.fetchall():
            flag = True
            cherrypy.session['reusedRun'] = True
    myConnection.close()
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    return self.database_failure(str(err))
```

But I don't know how to cobble all these different parts together to get a form where I have both the two client-side validations and the server-side validation.

Comment: I think you can just combine all form validation on form submit.however server side logic related check should be handle seperatly

Answer (score 3):

On Submit event, you should have a method in your backend that actually intercepts the request and I think there you should be able to make a connection with your backend's logic.

Here they are the steps:

1. Form compiled correctly
2. Http POST request starts `onSubmit` event
3. Back-end receives the request and applies further logic by gathering the data on the method in charge to receive the Http POST request

Otherwise, you may try to make an **AJAX** call on which there will be executed the client-side validations and then it will call the server-side method/class for checking that `runname` has been used already.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times I use custom styles to achieve this.

```css
.invalid-feedback{
  display:none;
}

.invalid .invalid-feedback {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<form novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Label</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="runname" type="text">
    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

In Javascript

Validate the input controls and set css classes and message text.In your case, validate not empty, no spaces, and not already used[server side]. 
If invalid add the class `invalid` to parent `form-group`, and set the validation message inside `invalid-feedback` div next to the input control.

Comment: Well it doesnt update the message after showing server side error message. Ex: I displayed "Email is already taken." in invalid-feedback element. Then, I clear email field and try to submit. It didn't show the right message for empty field. Is there anyway to handdle that?